# How to add a Video and Music folder to XBMC

Tags: 12.04, xbmc

I have a Video folder and a Music Folder and I want to add them both to XBMC. Both folders have several sub-folders that contain many songs or many videos.

I tried importing the list and selecting the video folder in the video category in XBMC with no luck. How can I import this folders to XBMC. A easy to follow guide would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways .... you can either add a watch folder or navigate to it....

1. Go to Music > Files
2. Select Add Source
3. Select Browse and browse to your music directoy, after adding the  should be replaced by your path to music directory
4. If you have more directories to add, select add and the browse, you should now have two entries to your music path
5. Give Name below Enter a Name for the media source, say Music Local
6. Select OK

Select OK

Now you'll get a Music Local in your Music> Files

Highlight it, Press 'C' and select **Scan for new Content**

to update library on startup [in case you are frequently adding songs, tough i dont recommend if you have a huge llibrary]

System > Music > Library

Select Update Library on Startup and enable it.

For Videos Steps are pretty Much same except

after step 4 you may encounter a pop up of **SET CONTENT**

**4.1** Select wether that folder contains Movies/TV Shows/Music VIdeos,

**4.2** Choose a Scrapper, IMDb for Movies, TVdb for tv shows are preffered

**4.3** Enable Run automated scan

**4.4** Edit the the movies in sperate folder as per your arrangement in folders [eg, say you have a movie folder called **moviez**, and you store all movies in that folder than disable that option, or else if you have a seperate folder for every movie inside the main Moviez folder leave it enabled]

**4.5** Leave Scan Recursively Enabled

**4.6** Exclude path from library update [select as per your needs].

Now press ok and resume as usual

Note: Videos may update immediately and you may not have to press c and scan for new content.

I made a video on youtube way back [XBMC Eden Preview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7Yl-V_PHcc), the comments might help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the Press C part. The rest is pretty good Sarvesh.

Comment: yeah many forget that it exists....!!!